# jQuery tab regarding change of .filter(':first').click();

Tags: jquery, jquery-tabs

Currently I have this code for jQuery tabs

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('.tab-section').hide();
$('.tabs a').bind('click', function(e){
    $('.tabs a.current').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-section:visible').hide();
    $(this.hash).show();
    $(this).addClass('current');
    e.preventDefault();
}).filter(':first').click();
});
```

The codes is working when I want to show the first ul a (i.e first link in the list) as per above. Anyone has any idea how do I manipulate the codes if I want to show a specific link in the list instead? Any help is appreciated.

`.eq(3).click();` instead of `.filter(':first').click();` answered by [PXL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/235710/pxl) works thanks

for the second question, is there a way to trigger `.filter(':first').click();` inside the `.filter(':first').click()` instead

Comment: Is there a way to trigger the .click as well to be inside the bind element?

Comment: UPDATE http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18044877/edit the question don't post in comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can target any of them with there index -

`.eq(3).click();` instead of `.filter(':first').click();`

Note that `.eq(3)` will target `4th` link as index starts with `0`

Comment: thanks that seem to work, however, Is there a way to trigger the .click as well to be inside the bind element?